# Async onClick Event

Tags: reactjs

I´m trying to update a state inside this:

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setConnected(true);
    console.log(connected);
    navigate("/chatroom", {
      state: { username, room, connected },
    });
  };

<button
            type="submit"
            className="btn"
            onClick={(e) => {
              handleClick(e);
            }}
          >
```

The problem is that the state is not updating when I click. I know is an async problem, but I´ve tried the other options asked in SO but I dont get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 ways to fix

The first one is using `useEffect` to listen to `connected`, `username`, and `room` values changes

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
     if(connected && room && username) {
        console.log(connected);
        navigate("/chatroom", {
          state: { username, room, connected },
        });
     }
  }, [connected, room, username])

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setConnected(true);
    
  };
```

The 2nd way, you can use class-based component instead of function-base component and then call `setState` with `callback`. Here is an example

```
setState({
  connected: true,
  username: "updated username",
  room: "updated room"
}, () => {
   navigate("/chatroom", {
      state: { username, room, connected },
    });
});
```

You can check the document [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it is an asynchronous issue, as when you update the state, it is not immediately updated.

So you should refactor your function, and use `useEffect`, to be triggered on `connected` update:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setConnected(true); // Update state async
};

useEffect(() => { // Triggered on connected update
  // You can add here a logic for handling your state
  if(connected)
    navigate("/chatroom", {
        state: { username, room, connected },
    });
},[connected])
```